# Finding the sum of specific multidimensional array php

Tags: php, foreach, sum

```
<?php
$bookrec=array(
'book1'=>array('callno'=>123005,'price'=>number_format(1380,2),'desc'=>'Attack on Titan Anthology'),
'book2'=>array('callno'=>123006,'price'=>number_format(844,2),'desc'=>'Binge'),
'book3'=>array('callno'=>123004,'price'=>number_format(598,2),'desc'=>'A Work in Progress'),
'book4'=>array('callno'=>123003,'price'=>number_format(668,2),'desc'=>'The Amazing Book is Not on Fire: The World of Dan and Phil'),
'book5'=>array('callno'=>123002,'price'=>number_format(760,2),'desc'=>'Children of Eden: A Novel')
);

$sumbook=array();

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><b>
    <td>Call Number</td><td>Price</td><td>Book Title</td>
    </b></tr>";
while(list($booknum,$rec)=each($bookrec)){  
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($rec as $data){
        echo "<td>". $data."<br></td>";
        foreach($data as $k => $val){
            if(array_key_exists($val,$sumbook))
                $sumbook[$val]['price']=$sumbook[$val]['price']+$data['price'];
            else if($k == 'desc' && $k == 'callno')
                $sumbook[$val] = $data;
        }
    }
}
echo "<br></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "TOTAL AMOUNT: Php ".$sumbook;?>
```

I am finishing this code for next week. Also, I am a student and just beginning in PHP. My problem is that I am trying to output the sum of `['price']` in the given array but it gives me this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach

I also tried various ways on solving this problem but I don't really get it. Please help. :) Thanks!!

Comment: get the price column using array_column and add using array_sum <?php
echo array_sum(array_column($bookrec,"price"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have lots of looping error just follow this code and also understand the how to iterate the array using `foreach`

```
    $sumbook=array();

    $total =0;
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><b>
          <td>Call Number</td><td>Price</td><td>Book Title</td>
          </b></tr>";

    foreach($bookrec as $key1=>$rec )
    {  
        echo "<tr>";

        foreach($rec as $key2=>$data)
        {

           echo "<td>". $data."<br></td>";

              if($key2="price")
              {

                $total+=$data;
              }

         }

        echo "</tr><br>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
    echo "TOTAL AMOUNT: Php ".$total;

    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to understand this.. :)

Comment: if answer is useful for you mark it with green ticks it's useful for future user reference @MNNarvaez

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$bookrec=array(
'book1'=>array('callno'=>123005,'price'=>number_format(1380,2),'desc'=>'Attack on Titan Anthology'),
'book2'=>array('callno'=>123006,'price'=>number_format(844,2),'desc'=>'Binge'),
'book3'=>array('callno'=>123004,'price'=>number_format(598,2),'desc'=>'A Work in Progress'),
'book4'=>array('callno'=>123003,'price'=>number_format(668,2),'desc'=>'The Amazing Book is Not on Fire: The World of Dan and Phil'),
'book5'=>array('callno'=>123002,'price'=>number_format(760,2),'desc'=>'Children of Eden: A Novel')
);

$sumbook=array();

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><b>
    <td>Call Number</td><td>Price</td><td>Book Title</td>
    </b></tr>";
 foreach($bookrec as $key1=>$rec )
{  
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($rec as $key2=>$data)
    {

       echo "<td>". $data."<br></td>";

          if($key2="price")
          {

            $total+=$data;
          }

     }

    echo "</tr><br>";
}
echo "<br></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "TOTAL AMOUNT: Php ".$sumbook;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first foreach loop had a wrong variable name with the one you initialized as your array.

foreach(**$bookrec** as $data){

}

Comment: Thanks for telling me the error. I'll correct it right away.

Comment: No problem, Happy to help